# Is it possible to creat some chat in a website to send message in an app?

Tags: android, viber

I wanted to create a chat browser that would send the message to an android app. For example, I do not have an app that my friend uses. However, I don't want to install the app. I will use this browser to send the message to my friend in his app. And when my friend gets this message in his app and he  replies from his app, Me on the other hand will receive the message in this browser.

Comment: you should use nodejs.

Comment: Or you could just use the web api from Google talk and have him receive the message in his Google Hangout application.

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing both apps? If so, check out something like Firebase: https://www.firebase.com/. It is suited for exactly what you are looking for. Real-time updates to all clients that are connected.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. No , i am not developing both the apps. One app would be already existing one (just for example lets say viber). Then I would like to send message to my friend in viber using a browser. My friend will use viber to chat with as normal viber user. But me on the other hand would send him message from the browser and not a viber app.

Answer (score 0):

These neat little App_Script created for Android with browser compatibility should do the trick. This takes both an input box and a message box.

Doing the desired function of sending and recievings Messages. 
Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser)

Answer (score 0):

you will need to be in the same source Code as the other user or a mirror App like viber on the example you provided, on the other hand you could create an application to send regular texts to mobile phones, but that's another subject.